# Moving repository from Bitbucket to Perforce

Tags: git, migration, repository, perforce

I have been tasked with moving a Bitbucket repo to Perforce with as full a history as possible, but have not yet used Perforce. By reading guides and forums, I understand that Git Fusion may be a way to do this, but have some concerns:

1. Is it necessary to install Git Fusion as a Perforce admin? Some parts of the documentation and forum discussions allude to this, but it isn't clear if some paths do not require it, and if these paths are sufficient for my needs.
2. Will there be limitations on the history kept in Perforce? Specifically, I understand that Perforce cannot map all of Git's constructs fully.
3. How do I cleanly remove git Fusion from the equation once the move is done? It is not clear from guides that I have seen whether "removing Git Fusion repo" also removes the repository itself, or just Git Fusion's involvement in it.

I presume that it is best to merge all branches before the move, and to completely stop using the Git repo after the move, for a clean cut.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Git Fusion is kind of a bridge that is installed server side.

If you are reluctant to install and uninstall the service on the server side, you can try using a git to perforce adapter on the client side.

Check git-p4 : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4

Here is a more complete resource from perforce, including pitfalls :
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2790?startURL=%2Farticles%2FKB_Article%2FGit-P4

You can probably write a script moving through your git master branch history and submit them one by one to the Perforce server.

I would be cautious with the following things before starting:

- your git hash will be transformed into perforce changelist
- I am not sure you can convert git tag into perforce label

So if you have documentation referencing them you'll have to update them as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did look a bit at git-p4, but didn't see a clear way to bring in code from a Git repo, and then move it to Perforce. I will have another look.

Comment: @CarstenWhimster : before doing anything your probably need to play around with Perforce to get a feeling of the features and restrictions. Something I have not mentioned is that with de 2015 release of Perforce & GitSwarm you can basically use Perforce as Git Repository, and keep working with the git client. This could also be something to consider in your situation.

Comment: Currently Git tags are not converted to Perforce Labels, but they are stored in Perforce when a repo is submitted that contains them. When a Git User clones/pulls the tags back out again, they can use them, but they have no meaning to Perforce User's at this time.

Comment: Xavier, I have some more experienced users guiding my use initially, and I am reviewing my proposed changes with them, so I will avoid messing anything up. We do want to use Perforce clients in the future, this is part of the task. The code was originally contracted out and stored in Git, but will now be brought in-house.

Comment: Jen, I only need to retain the checkin history, luckily. The build system will be done completely from fresh, and documentation is separate.